# How do I include jQuery in a project with babel, Node.js, and webpack?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, webpack, babeljs

Looking at the [jQuery documentation on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery), I'm confused as to what I have to do to use it. I know that I can just include the script tag in my index.html to use it, but how does everything else work?

If I choose to not use the script tag, I understand that I can install with node and then import it with Babel into any file that I want to use jQuery in. But where does webpack come into play? I only have to use webpack's require if I'm not using Babel, correct? Is webpack's require an alternative to Babel's import?

It seems like either I can use Babel and Node.js or webpack and Node.js? I thought Babel and wepback serves separate purposes though, with Babel trans-compiling ECMAScript 6 to ECMAScript 5 and webpack bundling all your files into one. If I'm currently using webpack, Babel, and Node.js. What is the best way to include and use jQuery?

Comment: Maybe relevant: http://blog.andrewray.me/webpack-when-to-use-and-why/

Comment: babel lets you write using the `import name from 'whatever'` syntax, and translates that into a `var name = require(whatever)` statement, but JavaScript does not currently have module loading, so it can't act on that `require` command without something like Webpack, Rollup, or Browserify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you plan on working anywhere without an Internet connection, go ahead and npm install the minified version of jQuery into your modules.

Otherwise, I would use the CDN in the HTML file for easy global jQuery access. It doesn't really make a difference how you include it in your project in terms of webpack/babel methods; just be sure to stay consistent with how you import them. The only difference is that require is ECMAScript 5 and import is ECMAScript 6.

Comment: This is not entirely true. I'm not sure if tree shaking has been integrated into Webpack yet, but when it is, another benefit of using `npm/webpack/etc` will be allowing you to only `import` the parts of jQuery you use, not the entire module. See [this article](http://www.2ality.com/2015/12/webpack-tree-shaking.html)